# How to activate suggestion lamp dialog box, when cursor is on it

Tags: android, kotlin, ide, warnings, preview

When Android studio is updated, android warning suggestions box not showing up when mouse cursor on it.
[image]

But when lamp is clicked box that i want to show appears.
[image]

How to auto activate it when mouse cursor move.

Answer (score 0):

Try to select the "intention bulb" option in the settings.
settings > editor > general > appearance

Comment: Thanks for answer but Its already selected

Comment: Maybe just trying to restart the program can help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why is occurred but, I deleted ".idea" folder. After that it is working as expected.